# How to setup alternate entry point in Blackberry application?

Tags: java, blackberry, entry-point, alternate

How to setup alternate entrypoint in Blackberry Application.There will be 2 application

1. UI Application
2. Background Application: will run on autostart.

There is a [blackberry knowledge center article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820&vernum=0) about this, which I tried, and coded as follows.  But on clicking the application icon, there is no response.

```
class EntryPointForApplication extends UiApplication {
    public EntryPointForApplication() { 
        GUIApplication scr = new GUIApplication(); 
        pushScreen(scr);         
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        if ( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("background1") ){
            // Keep this instance around for rendering
            // Notification dialogs.
            BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
            backApp.enterEventDispatcher();
            backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();   

       } else {       
        // Start a new app instance for GUI operations.     
         EntryPointForApplication application = new EntryPointForApplication(); 
           application.enterEventDispatcher();         
       }        
    }   
}
```

Class UI Application

```
class GUIApplication extends MainScreen {   
    public GUIApplication(){        
        add(new LabelField("Hello World"));             
    } 
}
```

Background Application

```
class BackgroundApplication extends Application {   
    public BackgroundApplication() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public void setupBackgroundApplication(){

    }   
}
```

I configured Blackberry_App_Discriptor.xml according to this [(edit) bad-link](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800901/How_To_-_Setup_an_alternate_entry_point_for_my_application.html?nodeid=800820&vernum=0)

Can any body help,where am going wrong.

Comment: BTW, your second link at the bottom goes to the exact same URL as the first link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try logging the value of args and (if not null) args[0] to see what's actually being passed into main().  It's likely a problem with your compilation process where the background module is not passing an argument (or not passing the correct value).

Also, try saving off your EntryPointForApplication instance into a static variable so that it maintains a reference (isn't garbage collected) and so that if the icon is clicked again from the home screen while it's already running, you don't start multiple instances of your app.  For example:

```
class EntryPointForApplication extends UiApplication {

    private static EntryPointForApplication theApp;

    public EntryPointForApplication() { 
        GUIApplication scr = new GUIApplication(); 
        pushScreen(scr);         
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        if ( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("background1") ){
            // Keep this instance around for rendering
            // Notification dialogs.
            BackgroundApplication backApp=new BackgroundApplication();
            backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();   
            backApp.enterEventDispatcher();
       } else {       
         if (theApp == null) {
             // Start a new app instance for GUI operations.     
             theApp = new EntryPointForApplication();
             theApp.enterEventDispatcher();         
         } 
       }        
    }   
}
```

Comment: Application.enterEventDispatcher() "under normal circumstances" will not return, so :
backApp.setupBackgroundApplication();
backApp.enterEventDispatcher();

is the correct order for this solution.

Comment: +1 Awesome way of having two different Applications (BackgroundApplication , EntryPointForApplication) running with just a cod. Most examples register an Application of the same class for each entry point. I'm going to experiment implementing different interfaces (PushApplication, GlobalEventListener) on each one.

Comment: @Marc, the static variable theApp is totally useless here. Static objects in BB are limited to the process - they are not shared between different app instances. The main method runs exactly once for each app instance, so the check for theApp being null will always succeed.