# BlackBerry Service?

Tags: blackberry

On my Android application I have Activities(UI)  and also Services(on startup) that run in the background concurrently.

I have an UI and behavior implemented and now I am trying to implement the background service portion on Blackberry. What is the BlackBerry equivalence of obtaining the same behavior of Android Services at startup?

Comment: you can use separate thread for the Services (HTTP connection etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the "Alternate Entry Point" mechanism of a BB app.  You can see [this related stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921029/how-to-setup-alternate-entry-point-in-blackberry-application) and also RIM has [some documentation](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/12002/Specify_AEP_settings_for_BB_app_proj_919731_11.jsp) on this.

Comment: In Android, I can start a Service from the a UI class or from startup. Alternate Entry Point would only be from a given entry point such as startup correct? If I start a thread from the UIApplication in blackberry will is continue to run in the background after the application is exited?

Comment: It all depends on how you code it.  You can code your app to run, complete a task and then die, or run forever in the background.  When your app is launched by the user, you can also code it to either die when the user exits, or continue running in the background when the user exits.