# My Application's main method does not work after pulling battery from Blackberry device

Tags: blackberry, program-entry-point

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to setup alternate entry point in Blackberry application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921029/how-to-setup-alternate-entry-point-in-blackberry-application)

I have made a blackberry application which need to run automatically after phone reboot (by pulling battery), when i pull the battery from phone and insert it again then i check from log file which I created on phone memory. By observing the log I found my Application's main method does not call after restarting.What can be the reason?

Comment: Searching for "+blackberry +autostart" turns up:  [How to setup alternate entry point in Blackberry application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921029/how-to-setup-alternate-entry-point-in-blackberry-application)

Comment: No i was not about alternate entry point...i was a silly mistake and some misunderstanding about the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this question does not make any sense. After diagnosing we found that every thing was working fine, but the only problem was that, after restarting (by pulling battery) it takes some time to initialize memory card, and my db and log file is stored on memory card. After detection of problem i shifted my log file to phone memory and i found every thing was OK. Now i put some delay on the stating of application, every thing is working fine as required.